# angular example for Multi-Column ListView - nativescript

Tags: angular, listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

this may be a really simple question from ur view but I didn't find a simple example anywhere

I found this already https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=VNkHaw&v=4 but it is not in angular and I am quite a beginner in nativescript (working about 6 months with it) so I couldn't use it or port it to angular.

so all I need is a basic sample or even plugin for multi-column listview in angular

Comment: The docs for `RadListView` aren't the friendliest, but they contain examples of how to implement the `Rad` plugins in either vanilla NS or NS with Angular; [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts) are the docs for implementing a multi-column `RadListView` in Angular, and [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/master/listview/app/examples/item-layouts) is the github repo which contains the example code.

Comment: As a tip, don't forget to import the `RadListView` plugin in your `module.ts` file. I don't think it's clear in the docs, but it should be something like `import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";`, then you add `NativeScriptUIListViewModule` into your `imports` array.

Comment: @BrianLin tnx it helped a lot, I wish u posted it as an answer so I could accept it as an answer, therefore I have to accept the only answer here (which is also helpful). again thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, I didn't want to post it as an answer since I didn't include any example code. Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Angular, you have to

1. Import the `NativeScriptUIListViewModule` in your module
2. Replace self closing tags with closing tags
3. Use directives instead of XML properties

Learn more at the official [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/overview), here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=7aVh8l).

Comment: tnx for ur answer, just a quick question here, is there anywhere that I can find playground samples? I mean something like codepen which has all projects list

Comment: Did you read the answer fully? I have attached the Angular Playground sample above. A full list of examples can be found at [this Github repo.](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/master/listview/app/examples)

Comment: Yes I read. ur link just opening `Basic Multi-Column ListView - @manojdcoder`, (maybe I explained my second question badly, I wanted someplace for all samples in playground). with a little search I found https://market.nativescript.org/?tab=samples&framework=angular&category=all_samples , so that means the second question is also solved. thanks

Comment: Market place has playground links to various UI samples, but we don't have a Playground that implements everything from NativeScript UI plugins. The Github repo is the only source that implements samples for all available features in the plugin.

Comment: I do what u said but now I have a problem in running and building my project. the error is `Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0)`,  I checked google linked but it returns 404 !!!!!!!!, I will be thankful if u help with this situation

Comment: Make sure you have installed the latest support libraries using SDK Manager from Android Studio.